# Grabbing data from webservice or file download in one Java call

Tags: java, web-services, csv

Is it possible to have one Java call that could download data from a webservice in CSV format or download an actual CSV file? Basically one call that handles both scenarios where you end up with a raw response in CSV format.

Will something like below that uses the url test.csv, also work for a webservice with the url /test.asmx that responds with raw data in a csv format?

```
public static void saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(String fileName, String fileUrl)
 throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
 BufferedInputStream in = null;
 FileOutputStream fout = null;
 try {
 in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
 fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
 int count;
 while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
 fout.write(data, 0, count);
 }
 } finally {
 if (in != null)
 in.close();
 if (fout != null)
 fout.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do you happen to have some code. Glad I know it can be done.

Comment: find a java servlet example, find a csv output example, put the 2 together.

Comment: You should probably re-word your question based on your comment to my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: I switched the word "and" to "or", not sure what will help.

Comment: Why not pick a csv java lib. Write csv to file. Have problems with that first step than paste your attempt on SO. Repeat for servlet **attempt**. Remember show us the code.

Comment: I dont have any code.  I was asking if you could make a request with one line of code, and it didnt matter if the URL was to a web service that returns raw CSV format data, or an actual file on the server in CSV format.  The response could be turned into a string for parsing.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. HTTP makes no inherent distinction between dynamically-generated and static data; there are often subtleties with headers, but they don't affect code like this.

P.S. you have just implemented `wget`, and of course this is not specific to csv files.

Comment: Ok thanks I just wanted to post some code so everyone can get a visual since everyone was having a hard time understanding.  Do you recommend this code, or is there a better function to use to do what I want?

Comment: Seems fine; the only thing I would say is it may not be necessary to save it to a file, depending on what you want to do with it afterwards.